# Falling object in specific time

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation

I want the object falling start from frame 250 until 350. But, I can't find where to set it. It always starts at 1.

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8483 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74004 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26792 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2122

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can either:

- Make the physics begin at frame 250 in the *Scene* settings > *Rigid Body World > Simulation Start*:

[image]

- Or you can activate the object's rigid body *Animated* option at frame 0, which means it won't be submited to any physic simulation, keyframe, disable it at frame 250 and keyframe again (deactivate and activate *Dynamic* will work as well):

[image]