# Rigid body simulation - How can I start it from the frame I want not frame 0?

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation

I have made a sphere explode with cell fracture, a rigid body simulation, a force field placed inside it, and not gravity.

I wish to simulate a debris explosion in space.

My only problem is that I would like the explosion to start at frame 233 of a 250 frame scene and not from frame 0.

Is there a way to start the simulation at the frame I want and maybe make it salt a bit longer so that the debris flies further apart in space?

Thanks for the help.
[image]

Comment: you can keyframe the Dynamic or Animate options, see here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26792/how-to-offset-the-start-of-rigid-body-physics-to-a-specific-frame

Comment: I managed it by baking the simulation at the Cache option of the Scene world tab thanks.